# Как загрузить SQLite-файл базы данных приложения c устройства на Android?

Tags: android-sdk, sqlite, android

Например, БД следующим образом:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Если действие происходит на эмуляторе то можно зайти в */data/data/com.example.myapp* и получить доступ к файлу с базой данных. На устройстве же такого доступа нет. Как можно скачивать и загружать файл с БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два способа - первый - порутать телефон. Тогда можно будет все делать. Второй - сделать в самой программе возможность выгружать базу, так как она имеет доступ к своим файлам.

Comment: А автоматические обновления на ОС Android потом нормально будут ставиться?

Comment: и да и нет. Все зависит от производителя телефона. В некоторых версиях могут рут и отобрать, некоторые откажутся устанавливаться.